# Radius of convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_n\neq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and such that $P_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kX^k$ splits over $\mathbb{R}$ and has no multiple root. I have to show that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_nx^n$ is $+\infty$. There was an indication : first show that
$$\sum_{\lambda\text{ root of }P_n}\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$$
is independent of $n$ for $n\geqslant 2$. I found out how to prove this but I don't know how to relate this to the initial problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does splits over $\mathbb{R}$ mean?

Comment: All the roots of $P_n$ are in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Are the $a_n$ real ?

Comment: Yes they are all real

Comment: @Tuvasbien was this a problem in a book? why do they say "has no multiple root"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By Cauchy-Hadamard theorem, the radius of convergence of the series $\{a_nx^n\}$ equals $\left(\lim \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\right)^{-1}$. By Vieta’s formulae, 
$\left|\tfrac{a_0}{a_n}\right|=\left|\prod _{\lambda\text{ root of }P_n} \lambda\right|$ for each $n$. Thus
$$|a_n|=|a_0|\cdot \left| \prod _{\lambda\text{ root of }P_n}\frac 1{\lambda}  \right|\le 
|a_0|\left(\frac 1n \sum_{\lambda\text{ root of }P_n}\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\right)^{n/2},$$ 
which tends to zero when $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: did you use "has no multiple root"? the proof that $\sum_\lambda \frac{1}{\lambda^2}$ is independent of $n$ does not use "has no multiple root".

Comment: @mathworker21 I didn't use "has no multiple root".